# Pre rendering and post rendering in oracle apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Could anyone please let me know what is the difference between **Pre rendering** and **Post rendering** in Oracle APEX ?

Oracle APEX version: *5.0.4.00.11*

Thanks In Advance,
Abhishek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arie provides a good explanation [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2180977). It all relates to when the regions on the page were rendered, much like the sequences that order those regions.

It does not relate to dynamic actions that may execute after a page loads.

Like Arie, I've rarely used the 'after region' computations, and I'd be curious what people may use them for.

Comment: I've never used them either. Maybe they might be useful where a particular value for an item should be used for rendering (e.g. conditions) but different for any subsequent page processing?